# Can QGIS analyse a personally created DEM to find transport links or place infrastructure?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, transportation, infrastructure

I'm working on game development and I'm trying to use QGIS to help me show some features on a created landscape.

I have used a diamond square algorithm in excel to create randomly generated 'worlds', taken the data for one of these worlds and converted to a csv file to import into QGIS as a vector layer. From this I have created a DEM raster layer, calculated channel networks and assigned land use.

My next hope is to add transport links and infrastructure onto this map, and I wondered if this was possible to do in QGIS or whether the problem was too complex?

Comment: How is the DEM connected to the transport network?

Comment: I think this is why I'm having a problem, I might be asking too much of what QGIS can do. I just wondered whether an algorithm exists which can analyse the DEM and place roads on top of it, where it feels that they can lie (possibly by assigning start and end points of a road). It seems like it could be a colossal task. Sorry if I asked too much, it's just an algorithm like this would help me immensely.